# What is the meaning of ifft2(H)(l)

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I want to calculate $$f(l): = \frac{1}{{{N^2}}}\sum\limits_{{k_1},{k_2} = 0}^{N - 1} {{e^{2\pi ikl'/N}}H(k)}, $$
where $l=(l_1,l_2)\in\{0,\ldots,N-1\}^2$.

ifft2 in MATLAB can be used to calculate $f(l)$. Someone wrote that $$f(l)=\mbox{ifft2}(H)(l).$$

What is the meaning of $\mbox{ifft2}(H)(l)$? Here $H$ is a $N\times N$-martrix. iffft2 also gives a $N\times N$-martrix, let's say $\hat H$. Then does $\mbox{ifft2}(H)(l)$ mean that the element of $\hat H$ at $l$? Thanks.

This step is embedded in my big project. But I think there is no bug in other parts. I am not sure whether there is some problem with this ifft2. I did not find the original formulas of ifft2 in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1) Do we agree on the right definition of a 2D DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) either direct or inverse (which, in Matlab, cooreponf to fft2 and ifft2)?

It should be, with $k=(k_1,k_2)$ and $l=(l_1,l_2)$:

$$h(l): = \frac{1}{{{N^2}}}\sum\limits_{{k_1} = 0}^{N - 1}\sum\limits_{{k_2} = 0}^{N - 1} {{e^{2\pi ik(l.k)/N}}H(k)}$$

with $l.k$ = dot product, (what you denote $lk'$) i.e., developed:

$$h(l_1,l_2): = \frac{1}{{{N^2}}}\sum\limits_{{k_1} = 0}^{N - 1}\sum\limits_{{k_2} = 0}^{N - 1} {{e^{2\pi ik(l_1k_1+l_2k_2)/N}}H(k_1,k_2)}$$

2) My answer to the question is that $ifft2(H)$ being an $N \times N$ array, the only meaning that can be given to $ifft2(H)(l)$ is that $l$ is a certain *index set* that extracts something out of the array, for example a first column like in the following example: m=rand(3),I=[1,2,3],m(I)'.

Comment: Indeed. your formulas are exactly what I wrote. Do you mean that the index of $\hat H:=\mbox{ifft2(H)}$ runs over $(l_1,l_2)\in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}$, i.e., $h(l_1,l_2)=\hat H(l_1,l_2)$?

Comment: I won't say that, I say something that you surely well know, that an efficient way to work with 1D or 2D arrays in Matlab is to use indexes? So once you have obtained your transformed array, ifft2(H), you may transform it by indicating the permutation on row and columns you desire, for example, m=rand(3),I=[1,2,3],m(1:3,3:-1:1) will permut columns 1 and 3 of the matrix.

Comment: In the end of my last comment, I want to say $h(l_1,l_2)$ is the value of $\hat H $ at the index $(l_1,l_2)$. I am not clear with your suggestions. Could you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: What are the dimensions of l in the writing $f(l)=\mbox{ifft2}(H)(l)$ ? $1\times 1, 1 \times N, N \times N $ ?

Comment: $l$ is of two dimensions, and $H, \mbox{ifft2}(H)$ are of $N\times N$. $f(l)$ should be a real number.